# Unable to start uwsgi service

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, systemd

I'm deploying python flask app in uWSGI. I followed this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I can;t seem to deploy my app on uwsgi.

When I execute manually the ff command:

```
exec /app/myapp_be/myapp_be_env/bin/uwsgi --ini /app/myapp_be/myapp.ini
```

It does work! However, if I try to start uwsgi.service (which is contained in /etc/systemd/system/) through "service uwsgi start", it returns the ff:

"Starting app server(s): uwsgi -> ! failed!"

I tried checking the logs in /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log. here's what i see:

```
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - detected number of CPU cores: 2
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - current working directory: /
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/pid
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - detected binary path: /app/myapp_be/myapp_be_env
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - chdir() to /app/myapp_be
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - your processes number limit is 1048576
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - *** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - uWSGI http bound on 0.0.0.0:5000 fd 3
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket fd 7
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - setgid() to 33
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - setuid() to 33
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - mapped 436608 bytes (426 KB) for 5 cores
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Mon Jan  7 01:33:48 2019 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 7746)
```

Here is my myapp.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
binary-path = /app/myapp_be/myapp_be_env
virtualenv = /app/myapp_be/myapp_be_env
chdir = /app/myapp_be
module = main_backend_app
python-path = /app/myapp_be
workers = 4
callable = app
master = true
processes = 5
plugin = python27
http = 0.0.0.0:5000
chown-socket = www-data
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true
emperor = true
enable-threads = true
home = /app/myapp_be/myapp_be_env
die-on-term = true
```

Here is uwsgi.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myapp
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/app/myapp_be
ExecStart= /app/myapp_be/myapp_be_env/bin/uwsgi --ini /app/myapp_be/myapp.ini
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I can't say what exactly is wrong but you seem to have mixed up the Emperor (multi-app) mode with the single app mode. I suggest you to stick to one tutorial only.

Comment: in the tutorial i initially followed, it used an upstart script. when i did the same and attempted to start the *.conf file, it says unrecognized service. so i deemed that in the linux kernel of my host, the service files migt have been specified somewhere else (in etc/systemd/system).

Comment: by what you said, should i remove "emperor = true" from myapp.ini?